# how to set clicked list item in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, click, listitem, angular-ngmodel

I have a set of list items, each is clickable. Upon click, I want the underlying model to update to the currently clicked list item index. For example, if I click on the third item, I want my controller's $scope.current to be set to 2. Since the list items aren't standard form inputs, I cannot seem to use ng-model, so I was wondering what's the solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method attached to $scope, and pass $index (the current item ngRepeat index) to it:

```
$scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three', etc...];

$scope.current = null;

$scope.setCurrent = function setCurrent(index) {
    $scope.current = index;
};

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="setCurrent($index)">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice, we wrote pretty much exactly the same thing :-D  Here's a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VRK1qQDRvRY7Il8ZBTcl) if it's helpful for someone.

Comment: @Kristján - Thanks for the demo and the correction :)

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but I also want the change to reflect in the UI, so I also added a title: currently selected: {{current}} but it does not update automatically, which, I thought ng should somehow perform, given the right config...

Comment: It should work. I've modified @Kristján [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qrlSiH2bHeTqXNIQx2Al?p=preview) to display just the index.

Comment: thanks, guess I'll go ahead and recheck why it didn't work for me. Obviously it's as simple as I thought but sth must have broke :)

Comment: Ah, found the problem. I am using a design based on angled-navbar, which builds a generic directive for a navbar + an app-specific controller to customize it per app. The 'current' variable is defined inside the directive and the reason it did not update is because it was linked to the parent scope using 'current': '='. Once I removed this line, all was ok.